# set the data of list that is in mainactivity from the third activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have three activities so I want to set the list of data from third activity to first activity list, how can it will be done? Please help to tackle this problem.

Comment: do you need this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: 
Start each activity in order with `startActivityForResult` and return the result from the third activity.

Option 2: You can also use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` while starting the second activity and then start the third activity from result.  Read more [here](https://medium.com/@douglas.iacovelli/android-send-result-back-through-multiple-activities-finished-or-not-4c2ba9e95112)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocalBroadcastManager for it.For example you can refer [How to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)